# Undefined index error file $_FILES['file']['error']

Tags: php

FORM where I am trying to create a blog upload content and image

```
echo '<form action="basics.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
echo '<b>Upload a Image file</b>';
echo '<input type="file" name="file"/>';
echo "<br>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>';
echo '</form>'.PHP_EOL;
```

I get the error in the below line which says undefined index file

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $_FILES['file']['error'];
}
```

Comment: do this. `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
 {
 echo $_FILES['file']['error'];
 }` do this it will go away

Comment: I get no errors. I get the output 0. Can you show the error message you get?

Comment: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\project2\admin\basics.php on line 112 and line 112 has this    echo $_FILES['file']['error'];

Comment: @Rizier123: I get  Undefined index: file

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES['file']['error']) 
   && !empty($_FILES['file']['error'])) {
    echo $_FILES['file']['error'];
}
```

Comment: i have tried the above code ...but it does not print...$_FILES['file']['error'] is empty i guess..not sure how to fix this